# Data type mismatch in criteria expression with REPLACE and nothing to replace

Tags: c#, ms-access

**EDIT: I've solved my problem by switching to ACE instead of ODBC.  Likely this was some bug with ODBC?  In any case, this seems like the solution if using ACE is an option for you.
Putting this up here because stackoverflow is not allowing me to answer my own question so soon after asking.**

My adapter is throwing a "Data type mismatch in criteria expression." exception when trying to fill a DataTable with the query:

```
"SELECT updateTime AS [Time], updateType AS [Type], updateOperator AS [Operator], REPLACE(updateText, '\\n', '\\r\\n') AS [Update] FROM [updt] WHERE updID = '" + updID + "'"
```

The REPLACE function is used to make the newlines use the Windows style so that they display correctly in DataGridViews and other winforms controls.

The database is Access 2010
I am connecting via ODBC (not Jet)
The datatype of updID is correct, it is 'Text'.

The problem occurs when trying to grabs rows where 'updateText' has no \n characters to replace.  For any row that has '\n', it will function correctly.

Yet, when the program breaks from the exception, I can open the command object and take the command text and run it in Access without any problems.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem by switching to ACE instead of ODBC. Likely this was some bug with ODBC? In any case, this seems like the solution is using ACE is an option for you.

Answer (score 1):

enclose that field in an iif() function. basically if it is not null then do the replace. Otherwise keep it null.

Answer (score 0):

You might need an IIF function as Replace function cannot handle Null.

```
"SELECT updateTime AS [Time], updateType AS [Type], updateOperator AS [Operator], " & _
"REPLACE(IsNull(updateText, "", updateText), '\\n', '\\r\\n') AS [Update] " & _
"FROM [updt] WHERE updID = '" + updID + "'"
```

Comment: It should be noted that the issue is not that the column is NULL, but that there is no \n to replace.  There is still text, but it is a single line.  I also get a 'Wrong number of arguments used with function in query expression' exception.  Checking MSDN shows that ISNULL should take 2 arguments, yet even with that I continue to get the same exception.  Could it be because I am using an ODBC connection?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you replace the text first and then include in your query.

```
string strValue;
if(updateText.Contains("\r"))
    strValue=updateText.Replace("\n","\r\n");
else
    strValue==updateText;

"SELECT updateTime AS [Time], updateType AS [Type], updateOperator AS [Operator],"+ 
strValue "+ AS [Update] FROM [updt] WHERE updID = '" + updID + "'"
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: updateText is a column in the table. :)  The goal here is to replace the unix newlines with windows newlines as they get loaded into a DataTable so that DataGridView and other controls can display it correctly.